# Proactive messaging in botframework is very slow

Tags: performance, botframework, skype, skypedeveloper, proactive

I'm trying to send proactive messages using botframework. I have observed that the rate at which botframework is delivering is very slow(3000req/min). Can someone let me know what exactly I should do to make it faster.

All I'm doing is iterating over my users and sending the message using the below code.

```
var replyActivity = CustomActivityCreator.CreateMessageActivity(message, id);
var result = connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(replyActivity).Result;
```

Thanks in advance.
PS: My server is hosted in West US.

Comment: Chat channel(s) are you using?

Comment: I'm using skype channel

Comment: Are you using Node or .NET SDK for BotBuilder? If you continue to have issues, please open an issue on [Microsoft/BotBuilder](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) GitHub repository.

Comment: I'm using .NET SDK for BotBuilder.